# How to send a javascript array to Spring MVC controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I am trying to send a javascript array to Spring MVC controller..But I am getting null value..

My javascript Code:

```
for (var n = 1; n < rowCount; n++) {
            cells = rows[n].cells;
            data.push([
                cells[0].firstElementChild.checked,
                cells[1].firstElementChild.value,
                cells[2].firstElementChild.value,
                cells[3].firstElementChild.value,
                cells[4].firstElementChild.value
           ]);
}

$.ajax({
        url: 'addDetails.html',
        type:"POST",
        data:
{promo : data}
```

My Spring MVC Controller Request Mapping:

```
@RequestMapping("/addDetails")
    public @ResponseBody void addEntity(
            @RequestParam(value="promo") List<String> promo) throws IOException {
```

I am not getting any value in Requestmapping for promo.Kindly help Me..Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The POST Body can be recieved in `RequestBody` not in `RequestParam`, and secondly if you pass your array like `{promo: data}` it will be converted to `HashMap` or some `POJO` Object not the Array List, so directly pass the array like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'addDetails.html',
        type:"POST",
        data:data
```

and make your controller like:

```
@RequestMapping("/addDetails", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public @ResponseBody void addEntity(
            @RequestBody List<String> promo) throws IOException {
```

**UPDATE**
For More Data you can make a POJO Class:

```
public class MyData{
    private String lname;
    private String lstate;
    private String lrta;
    private String lse;
    private List<String> promo;

   ... Getters and Setters
}
```

and your controller should be:

```
@RequestMapping("/addDetails", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public @ResponseBody void addEntity(
                @RequestBody MyData myData) throws IOException {
```

Comment: I have other values also to get it to the controller.$.ajax({
  url: 'addDetails.html',
  type:"POST",
  data:{
   lname:lname,
   lname : document.getElementById('lname').value,
   lstate : document.getElementById('lstate').value,
   lrta : document.getElementById('lrta').value,
   lse : document.getElementById('lse').value,
   promo : data
   
   
  },

Comment: if you want all of them to send in one request you can make a Class and then pass that object in controller and it will be fine

Comment: @PUSHPARAJN i have updated my answer please have a look